# How to load all aliases of a domain

Tags: domain-access

I'm using the modules domain and domain_alias on Drupal 8.

I need to load all the aliases of a given domain.

I have tried the following without success:

```
$aliases = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')->getStorage('domain_alias')->loadByHostname('my.domain.com');

$aliases = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('domain_alias')->loadByProperties(['hostname' => 'my.domain.com']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it.

The 'hostname' is not a property of the alias. The way to get the aliases is:

```
$aliases = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('domain_alias')->loadByProperties(['domain_id' => 'my_domain_id']);
```

Note that 'my_domain_id' is specific to the domain that you are trying to get the alias for.